# problems when set session codeiniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

I have some problems when I try to save my variable in session. I followed all the steps to save in session but it did not work in any way until I tried to see if it was for the htacces but I could never solve it.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session', 'encrypt');
```

And this is my configuration in the file

> config/config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'caja_prymera';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

in the autoload I configured the library and this is my code in the controller.

```
  function solicitar() {
    $data['error'] = EXIT_ERROR;
    $data['msj']   = null;
    try {
        $json_service  = '{"tipo": "A","Nombre": "juan","cantidad_max": 3000}';
        $nombre        = __getTextValue('nombre');//validation
        $apellido      = __getTextValue('apellido');//validation
        $dni           = _post('dni');
        $email         = _post('email');
        $newdata       = array();
        $tipo_producto = PRODUCTO_MICASH;
        if($dni == null || $dni == '') {
            throw new Exception('Ingrese su DNI');
        }
        if(strlen($dni) != 8) {
            throw new Exception('El DNI debe contener 8 caracteres');
        }
        $json = json_decode($json_service);
        $session = array('nombre'            => $nombre,
                         'apellido'          => $apellido,
                         'dni'               => $dni,
                         'email'             => $email,
                         'tipo_solicitud'    => $json->tipo,
                         'cantidad'          => $json->cantidad_max,
                         'tipo_producto'     => $tipo_producto
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('deliverdata', $session);
        if($dni == null) {
            throw new Exception('Ingrese su DNI');
        }else {
            if($json->tipo == 'A') {
                if($tipo_producto == PRODUCTO_MICASH) {
                    $data['url'] = RUTA_CAJA.'c_preaprobacion';
                }else {
                    $data['url'] = RUTA_CAJA.'c_marca';
                }
            }else if($json->tipo == 'B') {
                $data['url'] = RUTA_CAJA.'c_losentimos';
            }else if($json->tipo == 'C') {
                $data['url'] = RUTA_CAJA.'c_noencontrado';
            }
        }
        $data['error'] = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $data['msj'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode', $data));
  }
```

And this is my code when i get the session in my other controller:

```
   public function index() {
    $data['nombreDato']=':D';
    $data['nombre'] = _getSesion('nombre');//_getSesion = $this->session->userdata
    $nombre = $this->session->userdata('nombre');
    _log(print_r($this->session->all_userdata('deliverdata'), true));
    $sueldo = $this->sueldo;
    $minAuto = null;
    $maxAuto = null;
    $plazo   = null;
    $minPrestamo = null;
    $maxPrestamo = null;
    $valorAuto   = null;
    $minInicial  = null;
    $maxInicial  = null;
    $cantPago    = 100000;
    $minIniPorc  = $this->minIniPorc;
    $maxIniPorc  = $this->maxIniPorc;
    $arr = $this->array_datos;
    foreach ($arr as $row) {
         $plazo = $row['plazo'];
         $minPrestamo = $row['mont_min'];
         $maxPrestamo = $row['mont_max'];
         $minAuto = $minPrestamo/(1-$minIniPorc);
         $maxAuto = $maxPrestamo/(1-$maxIniPorc);
    }
    $valorAuto = ($minAuto+$maxAuto)/2;
    $minInicial = max($valorAuto-$maxPrestamo,$valorAuto*$minIniPorc);
    $maxInicial = min($valorAuto-$minPrestamo,$valorAuto*$maxIniPorc);
    'mi_cash' == PRODUCTO_MICASH  ? $titulo = 'Felicidades!!! Tienes un 
    pr&eacute;stamo pre aprobado' : $titulo = '';

    $data['tipo_product'] = $titulo;
    $data['iniRango']     = round($valorAuto/100)*100;
    $data['minAuto']      = round($minAuto/100)*100;
    $data['maxAuto']      = round($maxAuto/100)*100;
    $data['max_cuota']    = round($maxInicial/100)*100;
    $data['min_cuota']    = round($minInicial/100)*100;
    $data['cantPago']     = round($maxInicial/100)*100;
    $data['mensual']      = round($minInicial/100)*100;
    $this->load->view('v_preaprobacion', $data);
    }
```

Please help me solve my problem

Comment: You should have post the error message too. So someone could understand.

Comment: I do not get any error messages when I print my data in session I get empty.

Comment: Set the save path some like `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/'` because you are using files not database.

Comment: I already tried to change the $config['sess_save_path'] in different ways but it does not work. I have other projects but in none I had this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To use the "files" driver `$config['sess_save_path']` must be set to the absolute path where the files are to be written. Documentation [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver).

Permissions to the folder must be set appropriately. Again, consult the documentation.

You might have other problems but I confess to not looking for them. You've got to get `session` setup correctly first though.